# converting an array containing arrays of arrays into an array containing object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am stuck into this problem.Hours have passed but couldn't solve it.It's quite confusing to me.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Input:

```
[
  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['lastName', 'Blow'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['role', 'clerk']
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['role', 'manager']
  ]
]
```

Output:

```
[{
    firstName: 'Joe',
    lastName: 'Blow',
    age: 42,
    role: 'clerk'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Mary',
    lastName: 'Jenkins',
    age: 36,
    role: 'manager'
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: *Hours have passed but couldn't solve* This implies you have tried something. Can you share few of the attempts. That way we can help you in pointing your mistake and with the correct solution

Comment: `input.map(array => array.reduce((obj, pairs) => { obj[pairs[0]] = pairs[1]; return obj; }, {}));`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What do you know? Do you know how to iterate over an array? How to create an object? How to assign properties to an object?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) methods to achieve the result.

```js
var data = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['lastName', 'Blow'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['role', 'clerk']
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['role', 'manager']
  ]
];

var res = data
  // iterate over the main array
  .map(function(arr) {
    // iterate over the inner array to generate object
    return arr.reduce(function(o, a) {
      // define the object property based on the element
      o[a[0]] = a[1];
      // return object reference
      return o;
      // set initial value as an empty object
    }, {});
  });

console.log(res);
```

---

With [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
var data = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['lastName', 'Blow'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['role', 'clerk']
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['role', 'manager']
  ]
];

var res = data.map(arr => arr.reduce((o, a) => (o[a[0]] = a[1], o), {}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I had similar code, but was waiting for OP to share efforts.